# Activerecord Rails HABTM relation search by ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have has_and_belongs_to_many association between two models Chat and User.

I need to search for a chats by chat_members (user_ids).

for example:

```
Chat.where(users: User.last(3))
```

Is there an easy way to implement this task?

Comment: `Chat.joins(:users).where(users: { id: ids_array })`

Comment: @MarekLipka it returns all chats for given user ids. My aim to return chat, which includes exact users.

Comment: I don't think this will be possible in pure AR, you would need to mix in some SQL as well. I am not sure if that works for you. If it does, do mention if you are using a RDBMS like Postgres or MySQL.

Comment: @erosenin I'm using postgres and if you know raw SQL query which can cover my issue - it will be great!

Comment: @KirillBerlin I am going to assume your association table is called `chat_users`. Also, the chats should have exactly the users in user_ids or at least the users in user_ids?

Comment: @erosenin I has relation similar to this post. 3 tables, one of it contains ids of two others chat_id and user_id